# jQuery innerHTML does not work properly (!)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to build an `<a>` tag and set it in a `<td>` of a table. The string is built perfectly but when I set this as the innerHTML using jQuery, the string gets broken. I can't figure out why this is happening? Any clues?

Here's the string I want to set in the `<td>`:

```
<a onclick='return EditIssueItemBatch('1c1e27a2-beac-4772-a26f-6a7e05529a65', '498ba483-ca06-4b23-b3a9-0085e4760ff1')'>Edit</a>
```

But here is how it looks after setting as innerHTML:

```
<A onclick="return EditIssueItemBatch(" ?498ba483-ca06-4b23-b3a9-0085e4760ff1?)? 1c1e27a2-beac-4772-a26f-6a7e05529a65?,>Edit</A>
```

And the following is my code-snippet..

```
var tr = $("#itemIssueBatchListTable > tbody:last").children()[data.Index + 1];
...
...
var strBuff = [];
strBuff.push("<a onclick='return EditIssueItemBatch('");
strBuff.push(data.ItemIssueBatch.ItemCode_FK);
strBuff.push("', '");
strBuff.push(data.ItemIssueBatch.StockDetCode_FK);
strBuff.push("')'>Edit</a>");
tr.cells[9].innerHTML = strBuff.join("");
...
...
```

Comment: Note that you are NOT using jquery when assigning a value to innerHTML - that is just plain javascript, so it has nothing to do with Jquery. Jquery way would be:

    $( tr.cells[9] ).html( strBuff.join("") );

Comment: Thanks Razor for reply. Escaping the string did it as suggested by David.

$( tr.cells[9] ).html( strBuff.join("") ) works too if I escape the string properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're terminating your onclick attribute at the end of the first `strBuff.push` call by using single quotes to both surround the attribute value and inside its contents - you must mix your quotes:

```
var strBuff = [];
strBuff.push("<a onclick=\"return EditIssueItemBatch('");
strBuff.push(data.ItemIssueBatch.ItemCode_FK);
strBuff.push("', '");
strBuff.push(data.ItemIssueBatch.StockDetCode_FK);
strBuff.push("')\">Edit</a>");
tr.cells[9].innerHTML = strBuff.join("");
```

In fact, the "desired" HTML you have written out in your question wouldn't work either for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

try `tr.cells[9].html(strBuff.join(""))` instead.